# How to get better image quality on QPixmaps even after KeepAspectRatio and SmoothTransition

Tags: python, pyside2, qpixmap, qicon

I am making a desktop application using the PySide2 implementation of Qt. Something this application needs to do is display high quality images to the user, however when I use the QPixmap class, images are always at significantly lower quality that the JPEG files they came from.

I have followed the advice of others by using the QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio and QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation tags, which did help a little bit, however the images are still coming in low quality and any small text in images is illegible.

I am using this code to display images to the user.

```py
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(os.path.join(self.imageFolder,
    imageSplit[0] + '_' + str(self.currentPageNum) + '_' + '0'))
pixmap = pixmap.scaled(self.imageWidth, self.imageHeight,
    QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
icon = QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)
self.imageIcon.setIcon(icon)
```

However as stated the image is coming in at significantly lower quality than the input JPEG. Is there any way to get higher image quality? If not, is there anything else that you would recommend me to do if I need higher quality images presented to the user?

By request, here is an example of an input image vs it's pixmap representation.
[image: Input Image]

[image: After used in Pixmap]

Comment: You could show the input image and an image of what you get

Comment: I have updated the post to show an example.

Comment: what is `self.imageIcon`? Why do you scale the images? The latter asks because QIcon directly loads the image without using a QPixmap, also provides a [MRE]

Comment: The QButton is 200x200. The pixmap is scaled because I thought that step would be needed to ensure that all buttons were the same size, however after commenting those lines out, I see that it is unnecessary. After removing the scaling, it appears that input images are now the same quality (or at least very similar) as their pixmap representations. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL; DR;** Upload the image to [QIcon](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html) using the path.

---

[QIcon](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html) can load the image without using the QPixmap, and when you paint it with the [`paint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#paint) method it will scale it using the geometric properties of that element.

If instead you scale it using QPixmap you will be introducing more errors due to downsampling / upsampling, in addition to smoothing it also adds more errors.